# Share URL similar to Facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= but for Houzz

Tags: url, sharing

I'm working with Adobe DPS buttons and currently have set up Facebook and Twitter sharing with them. The buttons take a URL and when clicked pull up the share dialogue.

The Facebook taking the following

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=(encoded url goes here)
```

The encoded url being whatever I want to share.

**I want to be able to do this with Houzz.**

I've found the page on Houzz.com but I don't think I would be able to use this type of URL share option based on what they provided.

http://www.houzz.com/buttonsAndBadges#houzzbutton

Has anyone seen an option for Houzz similar to Facebook's?

Answer (score 9):

After digging through Houzz's bookmarklet, I've found their somewhat difficult-to-pin-down sharer URL.

`http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?imageUrl=(IMAGE-URL-HERE)&title=(PAGE-TITLE-HERE)&link=(PAGE-URL-HERE)`

Just as a quick reminder: an image URL is required (unlike Facebook or Twitter, but somewhat like Pinterest) as one of the main points of Houzz is image sharing/scrapbooking.

I hope this helped someone!